# How do I get past the security door in DXHR:DC?

Tags: deus-ex-human-revolution

Specifically the one leading to the "Detention Center 5" in what used to be the "In the Belly of the Beast" chapter of the Missing Link DLC before it was merged into Director's Cut. 
Screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/y8Oak.jpg

I pressed the button to initialize the scan, but the doors didn't open and the objective marker moved to the other side. Looking at the map shows this as the only way through.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you already spoke to Keitner so you should pass the biometric scan. If so it seems to be a bug. You should press the button, enter the scan chamber, wait for scan to finish (which in fact is only a choke point to load next level) and, after that, doors should open allowing you to enter the detention center.